# Compiling error from Makefile: "Unable to open output file"…"No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, makefile

I found a project online (resurrecting an old robot) which I want to integrate into something I'm working on, but I'm having trouble compiling the makefile. I always end up with the error:

*c++ -c src/Apps/speechSynth.cpp -o  obj/speechSynth.o -Isrc*

*error: unable to open output file 'obj/speechSynth.o': 'No such file or directory'*

The file is:
https://github.com/jvalentine-20000/hero-pi.git

I'm struggling to see an issue with the makefile? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the error message (with my addendum):

```
unable to open output file 'obj/speechSynth.o': 'No such file or directory'
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since this is an *output* file (from `-o`), it's almost *certainly* because you do not have an `obj` directory. I'd suggest creating one.

In fact, since the `Makefile` should be doing all the work for you, I'd suggest changing the command sequence so that you do:

```
mkdir -p obj
```

immediately before the compilation. This should ensure the directory exists before trying to use it.

Comment: Makefiles CAN create (the obj) directories on the fly.  Perhaps your makefile does not?  Or maybe, do you have permissions?

Comment: @2785528, you generally have to provide *commands* for a makefile to create a directory. In this case, it's simply running the compiler, and I can't recall *ever* seeing a compiler auto-create directories (not saying none *can,* just that I've never seen one do it).

Comment: This was all super helpful. I assumed that the makefile would create the directories, so once I created them then it compiled correctly. Thank you!